# Conky program is not installed on ubuntu16.10

Tags: conky

I need to install conky manager to ubuntu,but write this cods for install conky

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

I get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree ... 
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package conky-manager
```

What should I do?

Comment: PPAs are not community-supported software, so why are you asking us? Ask the author of the PPA.

Comment: I do not know what to do. Please help me to install

Comment: What should I do to solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from the [repository in launchpad shared by yourself.](https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008)

Or simply download the `.deb` file (v.2.4 )for a 64bit Ubuntu install, [here.](https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/9408446/+files/conky-manager_2.4~136~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb)

More information on the owner's website:

http://www.teejeetech.in/p/conky-manager.html

Comment: Thank you , My problem was solved, by downlaod .deb file for 32bit ubuntu and install on

Comment: @Arefgh, If the answer worked for you, you could mark is as accepted (by clicking the tick at the left), this way future readers will know about it :)

Answer (score 0):

The PPA does not have conky-manager built for 16.10 (yakkety): https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=yakkety

You would need to install the Deb file yourself from the 16.04 (Xenial) packages they have.